# LittleProxy clientToProxyRequest Called twice

Tags: little-proxy

I configured LitteProxy as a reverse proxy and trying to implement a filter. When I send a HTTP GET , the clientToProxyRequest filter adapter is called twice. Once with **DefaultHttpRequest** as **httpObject** and the second time with **LastHttpContent**. It can be something to do with chunks ? How do I do this right ?

```
HttpProxyServerBootstrap bs = DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap();
    //reverse proxy
    bs.withAllowRequestToOriginServer(true);
```

Filter is created as :

```
new HttpFiltersAdapter(originalRequest) {
        @Override
       public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {
            //doing filtering here..
            return null;
       }
}
```

Comment: After some debugging, I filter the http request only if they are an instance of HttpRequest , something like :   if (httpObject instanceof HttpRequest) { //filter }. Works as expected so far but not sure if there is a better way.